# Using .find to search for element by id - Vue/Vuex

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex

I'm new to Vue and especially Vuex but I don't think that's my problem here. My actions and mutations are working great except the .find function is causing a problem when I try to increment(or decrement) a second time. However I am able to add one of each item, as long as the item does not already exist in currentOrder. I think this may be due to the if statements on both mutations? For context, this is an online menu, the menu is an array of item objects and currentOrder is an array of item objects with a quantity

```
mutations: {
INCREMENT_QUANTITY(state, payload) {
  console.log("VUEX INCREMENT: Payload ID: " + payload.id);
  
  //If item already exists in currentOrder, increment quantity;
  if(state.currentOrder.find(o => o.id == payload.id)) {
    var index = state.currentOrder.find(o => o.id == payload.id);
    state.currentOrder[index].quantity ++;
  } else {
    state.currentOrder.push({
      //currentOrder item
      id: payload.id,
      title: payload.title,
      quantity: 1,
    })
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < state.currentOrder.length; i++) {
    console.log(state.currentOrder[i]);
  }
},
DECREMENT_QUANTITY(state, payload) {
   console.log("VUEX DECREMENT");
   var orderItem = state.currentOrder.find(o => o.id === payload.id)
   //if item exists in currentOrder, decremenet quantity
   if(orderItem ) {
     console.log("if statement");
     if(orderItem.quantity != 0) {
       var index = state.currentOrder.find(o => o.id === payload.id)
       state.currentOrder[index].quantity --;
     }
   }
 }
},
actions: {
  incrementQuantity(context, payload) {
    context.commit('INCREMENT_QUANTITY', payload);
  }, 
  decrementQuantity(context, payload) {
    context.commit('DECREMENT_QUANTITY', payload);
  }
},
```

[Here's my console display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOd9o.png)

Comment: `var index = state.currentOrder.findIndex(o => o.id === payload.id)`. here use `findIndex` instead of `find`

Comment: `Array.find()` returns a reference to the found array element, which you could modify directly. No need to do another search. i.e., `const x = state.currentOrder.find(...); if (x) { x.quantity++; }`

Comment: This worked! thank you so much